# Twitter 3 legged oath for Twitter with PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Hi I am trying to get 3 legged oath for twitter working so I can post on behalf of my user. Can someone please suggest either a good tutorial and also PHP library of class that handles this for me. I have got twitter php working (https://github.com/dg/twitter-php) but I don't think it can do 3 legged oAuth. Any suggestions on what to use? Thanks

Comment: There is no 3legged oauth for twitter.  Twitter only allows for Oauth1 not Oauth2.

Comment: @DaImTo I think you'll find that Twitter does do 3-legged OAuth, see [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization).

Comment: @JonSusiak where were you 6 months ago when I tried to find that... I stand corrected now I need to go get it working.

Comment: Right found a cracking php code library that does it all and is easy to set up. https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth. Thanks for your help